# How to open link that is inside div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following div:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#">Test Title</a> <small>Aug 24, 2013</small></h3>
</div>
```

I want to make it so that when the user clicks on `.panel-heading` (any part of that div), it will open up what was linked to `Test Title`. In this case, it should open `#`. How do I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function(){ 
    window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mZPnw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally have gotten away with this by anchoring the whole div like so

```
<a href="#"><h3 class="panel-title">Test Title<small>Aug 24, 2013</small></h3></a>
```

Comment: Sorry I wrapped just the H3, put anchors around whole div

Comment: This is valid in HTML5, but with other doctypes this is technically invalid to have a block element inside an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 $('.panel-heading').click(function(){
    element.find(">:first-child").click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to just wrap the div with the link:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Test Title <small>Aug 24, 2013</small></h3>
    </div>
</a>
```

However if you must use javascript...

```
$( ".panel-heading" ).on( "click", function() {
    var tgt = $( this ),
        href = $( "a", tgt ).attr( "href" );
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you might be better off having the `<a>` include the date there as well, and styling it with display:block so that it fills the div.  Then no JS would be needed.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#">Test Title <small>Aug 24, 2013</small></a></h3>
</div>

.panel-heading a {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

personally, in a situation like this, assuming you are in control of the HTML, I would write it like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-href="#">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Test Title <small>Aug 24, 2013</small></h3>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('href')) {
        location.href = $(this).data('href');
    }
});
```

Then you could style the HTML however you like, adding any kind of text decoration you wish.
Of course, this approach has it's advantages and drawbacks, the advantages being you can globalize this function by using a generic class such as 'link', and have the click event attached to a jQuery selector that selects that class, so that you can have multiple elements in your HTML code that are controlled by one function. The most obvious drawback to this approach is that the browser functionality of previewing an anchor link is disabled, but of course you could add the title attribute to give an alternative view of the same information.